# Is there a way to prevent web services from knowing that I am using a proxy to connect?

Tags: vpn, proxy, tor

Is there a way to prevent web services from knowing that I am using a proxy to connect?

Many web services block access if you're using a proxy, even if you are only doing it to protect yourself from eavesdropping by corrupt governments and even if your intent is legit and otherwise in accordance with the website TOS.

Can anyone answer the question above?

Alternatively, is there a proxy similar service which is impossible to detect?

I have tried with proxies, VPN and TOR already, they are all detected as proxies.

Comment: Please don't be rude. If the owner of a service doesn't want you to use that service, please respect their wishes rather than trying to find some way to trick them. You are welcome to try to bypass eavesdropping by corrupt governments if you wish to do that, but you are not welcome to trick others into cooperating with your efforts when they do not wish to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So you're trying to bully someone for asking a technical question, yet you are openly instigating to riot against government. I think I know where you live, must be the land of the free. And I think I know where you work :-)

Comment: It is your absolute right to not disclose any information. Could you please clarify what kind of proxy you are using in relation to your premises? The external one or that is set up at your home server?

Comment: First one who gives me a correct, technical answer gets a free image of a cat.

Comment: I have a lot of images of dogs, free of charge). Please clarify your problem

Comment: Serge, I strongly agree with what your saying - it's the right of every netizen not do disclose any information, indeed it can be dangerous to do so when and if the local regime is corrupt. I have tried all sorts of web proxies, VPN and TOR to no avail. External one.

Comment: I'm not trying to bully you for asking a technical question. I am, however, pointing out that you are asking how to use something that belongs to someone else in a way that they specifically do not wish it to be used. I am not instigating anything except not tricking others to join in your cause against their wishes.

Comment: You did not give an answer to my question, though.

Comment: I agree that "it's the right of every netizen not do disclose any information, indeed it can be dangerous to do so when and if the local regime is corrupt". However, it is absolutely *not* your right to force me to cooperate with your effort against my wishes. You are asking how to force others to assist you in this effort when they have explicitly configured their systems to prevent you from doing this to them.

Comment: All routers got down...

Comment: Your question, Serge: Could you please clarify what kind of proxy you are using in relation to your premises? The external one or that is set up at your home server? Answer: It is an external service, I suppose. I have tried online proxies. And a VPN. And Tor. Don't know what other information I can give you.

Comment: I think you might live in the United States, so it is good idea to use a proxy service. Some websites are just stubborn and insistent though.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The server must send information back to you for you to see a result, if the address you provide to the server to send the return message is on a list of "Do not send information to these addresses" there is nothing you can do to change that.

Your only three options are:

1. Attempt to find a proxy service that is not blocked by the site you wish to use (free or paid, you may have better luck with a paid VPN service).
2. Not use the site proxied.
3. Set up your own private proxy by paying for a server somewhere like [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) and setting up the proxy software yourself for you (and only you, so it does not get blacklisted) to use.

Comment: Basically, freedom of the press belongs to them what owns the press, so if you want freedom of the press, go buy your own press.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I was going to rebuke you, but you are right! Freedom of the press does not mean "free presses". You are allowed to say whatever you want, the government (or anyone else for that matter) is not required to help you get your message out.

Comment: Exactly. You may complain about "freedom of speech" because someone removes your comment from their blog, they have that right. So if it's so important, (and we have to face it that too many FOS complainers often are trolls) then get your own blog and get your opinions heard. Nothing is stopping you from running any sort of service (blog, proxy, website) you desire unless it's your technical inexpertise, so in that case a little self education can produce a lot of empowerment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want avoid detection, you may be interested how detection can be done.
The website has several option:

1. It can check the HTTP header, looking for [X-Forwarded-For (XFF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP header field. Most legitimate proxy does this (this will reveal your originating address). To counter: **use other / your own proxy.**
2. It can check cookies. If you are on it's ban list (i.e because you repeatedly try to connect with different proxies) it can identify you by it's cookies.  To counter: **use 'incognito' mode / turn off / clear cookies**
3. It can use IP blocklist(s) to ban wide range of unwelcome addresses. You can disguise your IP (using TOR), but the problem is that, most possibly your real IP is the welcome one, and TOR exit points are on its blacklist. Tor exit points might be detected with [TorDNSEL](https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en), for example. Many (public/dark) VPN addresses might be on it's blacklist but not all of course. This way you can:

   - buy a VPN access as suggested by others and hope not to be blocked,
   - depending your real goal, you may want set up your own proxy (or port-forward) at some other location, or
   - hire access to a botnet if you want to go dark.

I would **highly discourage** you from the later one of course, but technically these are your options.

Strictly speaking, only method (1) is *proxy detection* all others are *heuristics* at best. The correct answer should be: do not send XFF header to avoid proxy detection. If you want to counter the heuristics see other options.